# Possible to security trim what web parts a user can put on a page?

Tags: web-part, security, security-trimming

Basically when you select Insert -> Web Part you get this menu:

[image]

Is it possible to determine what is available here based on a users role?

Answer (score 2):

I just came across [this post](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/controlling-available-web-parts-web-part-adder/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20WaldekMastykarz%20%28Waldek%20Mastykarz%29) from Waldek that might be useful for you.

Comment: Very interesting link.  In the code example he gives it does not go into much detail about where that would exist.  Would I put this inside of a webpart or something?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest.  I'll see if I can get Waldek to look at this.  I came across that post from Google Plus as I was skimming the forums here and thought it would be useful.

Comment: It's a delegate control and you can activate it on any scope you wish depending on your scenario.

Comment: Ok, I figured out what a delegate control is.  @WaldekMastykarz, do you know if it's possible to `Include` items in the WebPartAdder based on the group a web part is in rather than the `Recommendation Settings`?

Comment: Unfortunately with the default source you don't have that much choice: the Recommandation Setting is the only way to do it using the ootb source.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Web Part Gallery in your Site Collection.  Select the Web Part.  In the ribbon under the Documents Tab choose Document Permissions.  There you can manage permissions for the web part.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done. I've worked with the Web Part Adder class myself, thanks to Wictor and Anders. The class runs within the context of the user, so you can use that to possibly strip out specific web parts you don't want a user to see, depending on security role.

Keeping track of what specific web parts a user can and cannot see is up to you, as you have full control of the class which gets the web parts for the gallery.

Comment: So where would I put the code that works with the Web Part Adder?

Comment: Here's Wictor's article: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Dynamically-populate-the-Web-Part-Gallery-using-the-WebPartAdder-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx The block of code you want to focus on is the GetItemsCore() method, in there you'll implement the logic to trim which web parts to return. Note that this method populates web part into what is shown as a "Group". Might not be the result you're after though.